# Warning: Illegal string offset 'instance' in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update the php version of a wordpress website via ftp. I have downloaded and uploaded a new version of wordpress and the plugins used. But if I go to the website now I get the following error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'instance' in /home/e-fashionshoots.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/includes/class-theme-my-login.php on line 1073
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'instance' in /home/e-fashionshoots.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/includes/class-theme-my-login.php on line 1077

Someone can help me? This is de problem rules in the code of the plugin:

```
/**
 * Instantiates an instance
 *
 * @since 6.3
 * @access public
 *
 * @param array|string $args Array or query string of arguments

 * @return object Instance object
 */
public function load_instance( $args = '' ) {
    $args['instance'] = count( $this->loaded_instances );

    $instance = new Theme_My_Login_Template( $args );

    if ( $args['instance'] == $this->request_instance ) {
        $instance->set_active();
        $instance->set_option( 'default_action', $this->request_action );
    }

    $this->loaded_instances[] = $instance;

    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: same prob here some fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just change args default value in plugins/theme-my-login/includes/class-theme-my-login.php

from string

```
public function load_instance( $args = '' ) {
```

to array

```
public function load_instance( $args = [] ) {
```